# Getting the coordinates of an entity base upon its UCS as a base point

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, autocad, autocad-plugin

I am trying to move a UCS to a particular point and then get the coordinates of an Entity ,in this case a circle, based upon the UCS I just moved as its base point. The results of the coordinates obtained from code are incorrect (X3.0,Y5.5,Z0) which makes no sense. They should be (X2.5,Y0.0,Z0.0). 
after my code runs I can check the coordinates manually in AutoCad and the are correct. Not sure what the problem is.Any help would be appreciated.

```
    private static void UcsBaseCoords(Circle circle, Point3d newBasePoint)
    {
        var acDoc = Active.Document;

        CoordinateSystem3d coordSystem = new CoordinateSystem3d(newBasePoint, new Vector3d(0, -1, 0),new Vector3d(1, 0, 0));

        CoordinateSystem3d cosy = acDoc.Editor.CurrentUserCoordinateSystem.CoordinateSystem3d;

        var ecs = Matrix3d.AlignCoordinateSystem(cosy.Origin, cosy.Xaxis, cosy.Yaxis, cosy.Zaxis, coordSystem.Origin, coordSystem.Xaxis, coordSystem.Yaxis, coordSystem.Zaxis);

        acDoc.Editor.CurrentUserCoordinateSystem = ecs;

        acDoc.Editor.UpdateTiledViewportsInDatabase();

        var coodrsBasedOnUcs = circle.Center.TransformBy(ecs);
        acDoc.Editor.WriteMessage(String.Format("X{0}, Y{1}, Z{2}", coodrsBasedOnUcs.X, coodrsBasedOnUcs.Y, coodrsBasedOnUcs.Z));
    }
```

This is my dwg before I run my program.
[image]

This is after my program runs and it is correct. My UCS has been moved and If I check the circle's coordinates they are correct.(X2.5,Y0.0,Z0.0)
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer on the Autodesk community forum.

https://forums.autodesk.com/t5/net/getting-the-coordinates-of-an-entity-base-upon-its-ucs-as-a-base/td-p/7271185